# AWS OpenVPN to connect Multi Region VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn, amazon-vpc

I followed the video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AF3bGRqnKfk) and as far as I can see everything is set up correctly.

When I run

```
ipsec status
```

it tells me that there are two established tunnels and in the AWS dashboard it also describes both tunnels as being **UP**.

I've tried using

```
nmap -Pn xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

using the internal IP of the server in the VPC I want to connect to but it never successes.

Is there a better way of testing or do I have to use a different IP to force the connection to use the VPN rather than trying directly to access that IP address? I also feel like there's a chance I setup the VPN in the wrong direction so I have tested both ways using nmap with no luck.